# Flutter iOS. Fonts looks different in debug simulator and release device

Tags: ios, flutter, font-size

I've just noticed that Fonts looks different on the iOS simulator in debug mode and iOS device in release mode. It is kind of confusing. Any ideas why does it happen?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are using iPhone 7 device as same as simulator?

Comment: @canister_exister yep, I’m using IPhone 7.

Comment: check the "Text Size" - maybe is Larger Text, etc... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option to scale Text in iOS settings (Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Larger Text). This default OS solution, but if you want to block this inside your app you can do following

```
MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          child: child,
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        );
      },
)
```

Comment: Man apparently I have a lot of elder users with increased text size and if this solution of yours work I'll be so happy because I'm getting tons of complains about too big texts.

Comment: Thank you so much for this hint. You just saved me a lot of headache.